# Gmail + Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook + Outlook send mail as

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, outlook, synchronization

Win7-64 / Outlook 2010 / GASMO 3.5.370.990

We use Google Apps for Business. Our company main domain @abc with other domains (e.g. @xyz) associated. Our primary email setting is with the @abc domain. I have a need to change my default outgoing email to the @xyz domain by following these instructions:

1. Sign in to your Google Apps email (Gmail).
2. Click the  in the upper-right and select Settings along the top of any page, and select the Accounts tab.
3. Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
4. In the Email address field, enter your name and alternate email address and UN-check "treat as alias".
5. Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your other email address to confirm that you own it.
6. Locate the message from Gmail. Open it and and either click the link contained in the message or enter the confirmation code in the Accounts section of your Google Apps email settings.

After launching Outlook 2010, GASMO began syncing and completed successfully.

When composing a NEW message, the default FROM domain is @xyz, which is CORRECT.

Now the ISSUE I am having, is when I reply, reply-to-all, or forward an email, the default FROM domain is @abc, which is INCORRECT.  I can select the FROM field drop down and select the @xyz, and it would work just fine.  But I can't be doing this every single time.

How can I make this so that when I reply, reply-to-all, or forward an email, it will default to the correct domain (@xyz)?

Comment: The send as settings are not synced. Instead you should add the @xyz to the Outlook 2010 settings as SMTP account.